# Will a Keynote with a video in it export to PowerPoint properly?

Tags: keynote, ms-office

If I put a video in a Keynote presentation, and save it as a .ppt file, will the video work in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it with a QuickTime movie and was able to run the exported .ppt in PowerPoint as well. But this is probably no guarantee that it will work in all cases given the multitude of video formats, codecs, drivers etc. So in your case you probably get the best results if you

- start with a specific video format/codec on the Mac side (QuickTime and either MPEG4 or H.264 would be my first choice)
- do a test run yourself, maybe involving various target PCs (if this is a scenario you have to be able to work with)
- stick to the setup once you have proven it to work

Comment: Okay, thanks. At the very least, one format seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. The main difference here is that Keynote embeds files within it's own file,  alas Powerpoint does not. But i'm pretty sure Apple thought of that, thus it should export just fine besides the ppt file.

The best way to find out is to try it with a blank document in Keynote, import a video, export it as PowerPoint and see the result.

Did you try it already and did not get the expected result, thus the question?

Comment: I don't have MS PowerPoint available to me at the moment; I was curious as to whether or not it would work, hence the question.